# What unit of measurement is a BeV?

Tags: units

I am studying [this paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1968ApJ...154.1011G&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf) by Gleeson and Axford from 1968. They often measure the energy of a particle in BeV: does it mean GeV, like a *Billion of eV*?

Comment: Yes, that is an old way to say $10^9$ eV.  It's what gave the [Bevatron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bevatron) its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B is the prefix beva. It's an older prefix, but it checks out. It is equivalent to the SI prefix giga, $10^9$

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=beva&lk=1